# Replacing a column with 0 and saving it to a different name

Tags: r, replace

I am having problem with changing a specific column in a matrix and giving it a new name. Let's say

A = 
2 2 2 
2 2 2 
2 2 2

I would like to make  3 matrix which are

A1 = 
0 2 2
0 2 2
0 2 2

A2 = 
2 0 2
2 0 2
2 0 2
 and so on.

I tried a for loop with A[,i] <- 0 but this changes all the elements in A to 0.
I have tried A - A[,i] but this all the column of A are being subtracted by the vector A[,i].... Please help me!

Comment: "I tried a for loop with A[,i] <- 0 but this changes all the elements in A to 0." - no, it isn't.   It sets the i-th column to 0.

Comment: You don't need a loop, just do `A[,1] <- 0`

Comment: Here is an example with `lapply` that returns a list of your desired matrices: `a <- matrix(2, 3, 3)` and then `lapply(seq_len(ncol(a)), function(i) {a[, i] <- 0; a})`.

Comment: #lmo Thanks! This is what I wanted. And how do i assign each of this matrix in a matrix with different name??

Answer (score 0):

Building on @lmo's comment you can do:

```
a <- matrix(2, 3, 3)
x <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(a)), function(i) {a[, i] <- 0; a})
names(x) <- paste("a",1:length(x), sep = "")
list2env(x, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This is very helpful! I appreciate it!!